# As an user how can i terminate my account?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to add a feature in my portal for user if he don't want to be member of the portal anymore. If he want to leave his account how can he terminate his account.

Thanks 
Akash Jaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some foreign key relationships (not enforced on the database, still exist) on users, e.g. forum posts, blog posts and other content might have an author entry. Thus it might be hard to completely delete the user account. You might be able to deactivate the user, but there's no self-service functionality built into Liferay. It should be easy to achieve what you want through the API though. Look for [UserService](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserService.html) or UserLocalService documentation.